# Creating a root certificate in FiddlerCore

Tags: fiddlercore

I am using Fiddler Application to inspect / debug HTTPS , I found that when I am activating the HTTPS Fiddler Automatically Create and Install a certificate , is it possible to achieve the same behavior using FiddlerCore ?

Best Regards
Yuval

Answer (score 2):

The demo application included in the FiddlerCore package (see `Program.cs` in the `SampleApp` folder) shows how to enable HTTPS decryption in FiddlerCore. It generates the certificates as needed.

Note that you should follow the instructions in the source code (sync'ing the event handlers to receive notice of errors, and copy the makecert.exe file into the proper folder).